# Optimally returning a copied value

Tags: c++

I was rather surprised seeing following optimization introduced by Jonathan Wakely in libstdc++: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2018-05/txtc2I3IxLCfn.txt and tried to investigate it.

Given a couple of implementations of concat function for any non-trivial class, surprisingly only the first is optimal (one copy c-tor and one operator+= call). Others incur additional copy/move c-tor call - you can verify it at godbolt.org.

Why is that? I'd assume that all these implementation would generate same code with -O2.

Does the language specification mandate such behavior (if so why?) or is this an QoI issue?

This is consistent behavior between GCC and Clang on all versions and language versions.

```
void extern_copy();
void extern_move();
void extern_plus_assign();

struct myclass
{
    myclass(const myclass&)
    {
        extern_copy();
    }
    myclass(myclass&&)
    {
        extern_move();
    }
    myclass& operator+=(const myclass&)
    {
        extern_plus_assign();
        return *this;
    }
};

myclass concat(const myclass& lhs, const myclass& rhs)
{
    myclass copy(lhs);
    copy += rhs;
    return copy;
}


myclass concat2(const myclass& lhs, const myclass& rhs)
{
    myclass copy(lhs);
    return copy += rhs;
}

myclass concat3(const myclass& lhs, const myclass& rhs)
{
    return myclass(lhs) += rhs;
}

static myclass concat4impl(myclass lhs, const myclass& rhs)
{
    return lhs += rhs;
}

myclass concat4(const myclass& lhs, const myclass& rhs)
{
    return concat4impl(lhs, rhs);
}


static myclass concat5impl(myclass lhs, const myclass& rhs)
{
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
}

myclass concat5(const myclass& lhs, const myclass& rhs)
{
    return concat5impl(lhs, rhs);
}
```

Update: code modified to exclude problem with following implementation of operator+=:

```
myclass& myclass::operator+=(myclass const& v) {
  static myclass weird;
  return weird;
}
```

Comment: i remember from a talk i watched recently that copy elision requires in `return statement;` the `statement` to be the name of a local variable and that you can prevent it already by typing `return (x);` instead of `return x;`. Unfortunately I dont remember which talk it was nor can i give any other good reference

Comment: i think it was this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dc5vqt2tgA

Answer (score 12):

Copy elision (RVO, NRVO, and a special case of initialization) is a very special optimization: it is the only optimization in C++ that is not covered by the AS-IF rule. With every other optimization, the compiler simply modifies the program in a way that does not change the observable behavior, only the performance. But RVO can change observable behavior, because side effects in the elided copy constructor and destructor calls (such as output) are lost. This is why there is a special license in the standard for the compiler to perform this optimization, under very specific circumstances.

Specifically, RVO applies only if the return value is a prvalue, and NRVO applies only if the return expression trivially refers to a local variable.

The return expression in the statement `return copy += rhs;` is neither. It does not trivially refer to a local variable (it's a compound assignment expression, not an id-expression), and the return value is not a prvalue (your `+=` overload returns an lvalue reference, making the value an lvalue; this would be different if the operator returned by value, but that would be highly unidiomatic otherwise).

You may think that the compiler could inline the operator and discover that it's the same object, but the permission to perform this optimization is not given on this level.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this behavior is mandated by C++ standard.

Do you see any reason why the RVO/NRVO rules couldn't be extended to work in the cases like above ? (return copy += rhs)

Comment: That would require cross-function analysis and wreak havoc with separate compilation and possibly compile times.

Comment: I fail to see why it would be as problematic as you state.
Compilers already perform cross-function analysis (e.g. inlining) if they have function definition available, and since RVO/NRVO is optional already anyway, they could just not perform this optimization when function definition is not available.

Comment: @MaciejCencora They do that for optimizations, but not for language rules. And since C++17, copy elision is mandatory.

Comment: No, compilers don't/cannot perform such optimization now - because they are not allowed to per language rules (optimization cannot change observable behavior, and RVO/NRVO are exceptions to that rule). C++17 doesn't change anything in case of expression `return copy += rhs;`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
myclass& myclass::operator+=(myclass const& v) {
  static myclass weird;
  return weird;
}
```

It's perfectly legal!

Your reasoning is based on something that we take for granted: that the += operators will always return `*this`.

The compiler is not allowed to make that assumption.

In `concat()`, it doesn't matter, since we force the return value of `concat()` to be the instance of `myclass` on which the += operated on. In all other cases, the compiler must assume the worse unless it can guarantee that += returns `*this`.

Comment: Nope, that's is not it.
If you change myclass to following, you get the same behaviour:
`
void extern_copy();
void extern_move();
void extern_plus_assign();

struct myclass
{
    myclass();
    myclass(const myclass&)
    {
       extern_copy();
    }
    myclass(myclass&&)
    {
        extern_move();
    }
    myclass& operator=(const myclass&);
    myclass& operator=(myclass&&);
    myclass& operator+=(const myclass&)
    {
        extern_plus_assign();
        return *this;
    }
};
`

Comment: @MaciejCencora Huh, I am surprised the compiler didn't manage to resolve that. The underlying problem is still that references are not prvalues stays the same.

Comment: Care to elaborate more on the "references are not prvalues" problem ?
In concat5 function `concat5impl(lhs, rhs)` expression is prvalue (right?)